# Light diverter for bulb holder

Tags: light-fixture

I noticed the threads on the light bulb holder.

Can something be bought that will make the light shine downward?

As it is now, the light is too bright and wasted when it goes in every direction.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those threads *are indeed* designed for attaching screw-on shades. Usually I see them used for table lamps where the socket and bulb are pointing up and the fabric shade (open on top and bottom) diffusing light with no glare from looking at the bulb.

I would imagine it could work the same for you, just "upside" down... Try a lamp shop.

Comment: Specifically, you need a "Threaded Socket Ring", then that'll fit any lampshade you feel like.

Comment: I believe what I need is a 6x12x8 Threaded UNO Downbridge Lamp Shade. https://www.lampsusa.com/products/homeconcept-threaded-uno-downbridge-lamp-shade-white-6-x-12-x-8-061208ehwh?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3eb7ld-D5AIVhpOzCh0kNwflEAkYASABEgKJDfD_BwE

Answer (score 1):

### Try a bulb that aims light where you want it

Don't put a shade on it.  Get an LED "bulb" that aims the light exactly where you want.

If you wanted light in all directions, a screwball CFL certainly will do that. (As will an incandescent or a corn-cob LED, which intentionally aims light in all directions).

However LEDs actually generate a cone of light; out of the box they make about a 140 degree cone.  This is rather easy to attach a **lens** to, so lots of LEDs are sold with a narrower spread.

The most obvious focused LEDs are "PAR" types, with spreads from 90 degrees to as low as 8 degrees.